# How to handle the 3 hard Keys in Android

Tags: java, android

There are the 3 basic keys in an Android device.
 1. Home button (middle button)
 2. Menu button (left most button)
 3. Back Button (right most button)

I'm trying to create a code the use will press the Back button and a AlertDialog will appear before return to the previous activity.

How can I handle the back button and do I have to insert it on the onCreate on the Java File of an Activity?

Thank You!

Comment: It's not completely true. Some devices have 4 phisical buttons. And the tendency on some devices is to eliminate the menu button.

Comment: Oh! and I forgot to mention that you can manage the Volume physical keys and (not pretty sure about) the power button as well.

Comment: "There are the 3 basic keys in an Android device" -- no, there are not. *Some* devices have *some* keys. "I'm trying to create a code the use will press the Back button and a AlertDialog will appear before return to the previous activity." -- this is a UI anti-pattern. Please do not interrupt the user when they press BACK. Moreover, this does not handle any other way that the user might navigate away from your app, such as HOME or the recent-tasks list.

Answer (score 4):

All (4) buttons are handled differently.

The home button and running apps buttons are completely outside your control.

To get the BackButton press, override this function.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
    //Do Stuff
}
```

To get the Menu button key press, use the following

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keycode, KeyEvent e) {
    switch(keycode) {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU:
            doSomething();
            return true;
    }

    return super.onKeyDown(keycode, e);
}
```

After you show the user your alert dialog, you can either send a real BackPress to the system using `super.onBackPressed()`, or you can manually `finish()` your activity.

Comment: I typically use onKeyDown for both Menu and Back.  Is there a reason to use onBackPressed instead of using onKeyDown for both buttons?

Comment: @RobertNekic, that is actually just the way I have always done `onBackPressed`, because I try to never use the Menu key.

Comment: Huh...and I've never used onBackPressed.  I wonder if there are any compelling technical reasons to use one or the other to detected the Back button.  You've given me something to Google!

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed(){

    AlertDialog.Builder build=new AlertDialog.Builder(currentactivity.this);
    build.setMessage("Are you sure you want to return?");
    build.setCancelable(false);
            build.setTitle("Note");
    build.setPositiveButton("yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int arg1) {
        Intent i =new Intent(currentactivity.this,anotheractivity.class);
    startActivity(i);   
            //or just type finish();
               }
    });
    build.setNegativeButton("no", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int arg1) {

            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });
    AlertDialog alert=build.create();   
    alert.show();   

}
```